# How do I update a dropdown menu when another dropdown menu option is selected?

Tags: html, forms, drop-down-menu, contextmenu

Basicly I want DROPDOWNMENU2 options to update when a option option from DROPDOWNMENU1 is selected.

Heres some info:

DROPDOWNMENU1 :

Web Development
Graphics
Windows

DROPDOWNMENU2 (for Web Development) :

PHP
HTML
CSS

DROPDOWNMENU2 (for Graphics) :

PNG
JPEG
ICO
PSD

DROPDOWNMENU2 (for Windows) :

Seven
Vista
XP

Please help?

EDIT:

I'm trying to get this code to work

```
$('#topic2').change(function() {
$('#topic3').empty();
switch($(this).val()) {
    case 'Tutorials':
        $('#topic3')
            .append('<option>PHP</option>')
            .append('<option>HTML</option>')
            .append('<option>CSS</option>');
    case 'Graphics':
        // yada yada
        break;
    case 'Windows':
        // yada yada
        break;
}
```

});

HTML :

```
<form action="inc/post.php" method="POST">
Topic: 
<select name="topic">
<option>Web Development</option>
<option>Windows</option>
<option>Graphics</option>
</select>
/
<div id="topic2">
<select name="topic2" id="topic2">
<option>Tutorials</option>
<option>Article</option>
</select>
</div>
/
<div id="topic3">
<select name="topic3" id="topic3">
<option>Seven</option>
<option>Vista</option>
<option>XP</option>
</select>
</div>
<br /><Br />
Name:
<input type="text" name="name" />
<Br /><br />
Icon:
<input type="file" name="icon2" id="icon2"> 
<Br /><Br />
Content:
<textarea name="info" size="400"></textarea></div>
</div> 
</form>
```

Comment: Nothing, I've tried googling and no improvment.

Comment: Then try something and if you get stuck, come back with a specific question.  Stack Overflow is not the same as rent-a-coder.com

Comment: I think javascript will do it but I don't know how to do it in javascript.

Comment: Okay, I believe I can code that for you, but I charge $30/hour with all time rounded up to the nearest hour, and I require one hour paid up front.  Do you have Paypal?

Comment: I am not paying for a small bit of coding, if you code an example, I'll edit it to work with my dropdown menu.

Comment: Perhaps you should try [rent-a-coder](http://www.rent-acoder.com/).   Stack Overflow is not a "gimmeh teh codez!!!1" kind of site where you can get programmers to vomit up code for you on demand.  You have to put forth something that resembles effort on your end.

Comment: I just want some decent code for me to edit and render onto my site.

Comment: Then, as I stated above, **try something** and if you're stuck, come back with a **specific question**.  Either that or pay someone to do the coding for you.

Comment: I've posted some coding now, will that help?

Comment: Okay, what happened when you tried using the code above?

Comment: Absolutely nothing?  Were there any error messages?  What output did you get?  What was the expected output?  Do you actually want any help?

Answer (score 2):

I would use jQuery. Something like this...

```
$('#DROPDOWNMENU1').change(function() {
    $('#DROPDOWNMENU2').empty();
    switch($(this).val()) {
        case 'Web Development':
            $('#DROPDOWNMENU2')
                .append('<option>PHP</option>')
                .append('<option>HTML</option>')
                .append('<option>CSS</option>');
        case 'Graphics':
            // yada yada
            break;
        case 'Windows':
            // yada yada
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Do I have to put them on a DIV since they are using name="post"

Comment: @Lewes My code will do you little good unless you learn a bit of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). If you plan to be doing web development, it's worth the time. Google hosts the [code](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js) ([minified](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js)) which is convenient.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <form name="x" id="x" action="x.php">
   <select name="DROPDOWNMENU1" id="DROPDOWNMENU1" 
     onchange="javascript:document.x.action='dropmenu.php';
     javascript:document.x.submit();">
    <option>select web development graphics windows</option>
    <?php
        $q=select * from development graphics windows;
        $result=msql_query($q);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            if($_POST["DROPDOWNMENU1"]==$row[web_development_id]){
    ?>
    <option value='<?php echo $row["web_development_id"]; ?>'selected>
        <?php echo $row["web_development_name"];?>
    </option>

in DROPDOWNMENU2 select data  where DROPDOWNMENU2.id=$_POST["DROPDOWNMENU1"];
```

I hope this answer help you