# rally: How to get a dropdown updated automatically after I change another dropdown menu?

Tags: drop-down-menu, rally

I am trying to setup two dropdown menus. The values in one depend on the current value of the other. How do I link them in a way that when i changed the selected value in one drop down menu, it automatically updates the other dropdown menu?

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
<title>User Stories By Iteration</title>
 <meta name="Name" content="App Example: User Stories Table" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/1.32/sdk.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 var rallyDataSource;
 var relDropdown;
var table;
var relDropdown2;

function onReleaseSelected(releases, eventArgs) {
   var queryConfig = {
     type : 'testset',
     attribute : 'Name',
     query: '(Release.Name = "' + releases.getDisplayedValue() + '")'
  };
   relDropdown2 = new rally.sdk.ui.ObjectDropdown(queryConfig, rallyDataSource);
   relDropdown2.display(document.getElementById("releaseDiv2"));
 }

 function onLoad() {
   rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__',
                                '__PROJECT_OID__',
                                '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__',
                                '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');
  var relConfig = {};
   relDropdown = new rally.sdk.ui.ReleaseDropdown(relConfig, rallyDataSource);
   relDropdown.display(document.getElementById("releaseDiv"), onReleaseSelected);
 }

 rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);
  </script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
 <div id="releaseDiv"></div>
 <div id="releaseDiv2"></div>
 </div>
<br/><br/>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Possable duplicate: [Update dropdown menu when another dropdown menu is selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763564/how-do-i-update-a-dropdown-menu-when-another-dropdown-menu-option-is-selected)

Comment: Please provide some sample code to illustrate what you have so far.  SDK 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: I've added the javascript. sdk is 1.32. I want to make testset dropdown menu automatically updated when i change the value of release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDK 1.x dropdowns cannot have their values refreshed once they are rendered.  What you can do however is destroy the second dropdown and recreate it in response to the first dropdown's change event.

So in your onReleaseSelected just add the following code before creating and displaying a new one:

```
if(relDropdown2) {
    relDropdown2.destroy();
}
```

Comment: 2.x is in preview now but we are working toward a GA.  1.x is easier to get started with right now but 2.x is more powerful and more consistent with the newest product features.  Inline editing/re-ranking on grids, better boards, charting with HighCharts, etc.